# uploading file using javascript without ajax

Tags: javascript, html

I try to upload a file using input tag and type='file', i want to save that in my project folder. Can i do that with the help of javascript without using ajax?.. Is there any possibility available?

This is my code.

```js
function func3() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
  if ('files' in x) {
    for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
      var file = x.files[i];
      if ('name' in file) {
        alert("File selected. File name =" + file.name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="func3()">
```

Comment: I really doubt it

Comment: Yes, there is, AJAX. Use the tools provided for the tasks, it's rarely useful to try to do things "differently" ...

Comment: What u mean by tools...What type of they are??

Answer (score 0):

I think it's imposible, because security issue.

Comment: Ok... consider this...there is no need of any security issues, only for just an implementation can we do that?... that is what i'm asking..

Comment: I think you can't, it's imposible because browser do not allow that why because security issue.

Comment: Okay . Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

For file uploading in js you need to add two hidden fields one for file type
and other for file content. And you need to change file content into base64
and store into hidden field. See below code. Then use ajax to upload base64 content.

```
  <input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="func3(e)">
  <input type="hidden" id="fld-content" name="fld-content">
  <input type="hidden" id="fld-content-type" name="fld-content-type">
 function func3(e) {
            var files = e.target.files;
            var file = files[0];
            var fileType = file.name;
            fileType = fileType.substring(fileType.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            if (files && file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (readerEvt) {
                    var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
                    base64 = btoa(binaryString);
                    $('#fld-content-type').val(fileType);
                    $('#fld-content').val(encodeURIComponent(base64));
                };
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think using this we can read the file and write that in another format then we will save that with its original format... But if i want directly save the uploaded file with the type of the file whatever it may be (like txt, png, jpg, gif)..can i do that with the way of i'm asking??........

And tell me onething is the above code  ok for any format??

Comment: No you can't save file directly you have to change it to base64 format and in server side you need to convert back to file format and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is a way to take client data and send it asynchronously to a server without using the a window as a HTTP client to display the response. So if you want to upload a file and not trigger a "page reload" then your options are limited to AJAX or (and please don't do this one) using a hidden iframe and point the form there. If you want to store the uploaded file in the browser itself then you can do it without AJAX and use the browsers databases (Localstorage, etc) but this will not upload the file to your server.